# Алгоритм комбинаций

Tags: алгоритм, любой-язык

Помогите с решением задачи. 
Есть строка: "abcd", нужно вывести все возможные комбинации с разделителем "_", на выходе должно получиться что-то вроде:

```
a_b_c_d
a_b_cd
a_bc_d
ab_c_d
a_bcd
ab_cd
abc_d
```

Upd: длина строки может быть разной, "abcd" - показана как пример.

Answer (score 4):

4 символа - 3 промежутка, где знак подчеркивания или есть, или нет. Так что цикл от *000<sub>2</sub>* до *111<sub>2</sub>* и вставка подчерков в соответствии с маской. Если символов больше, то и ширина битовой маски соответственно больше.

Добавление по подсказке [Yaant](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/32625/yaant): Если какие-то комбинации не нужны - её или их несложно пропустить.  В приведённом примере это то, что соответствует полностью нулевой маске, т.е цикл нужно организовывать от *001<sub>2</sub>* до *111<sub>2</sub>*.

Comment: Благодарю. Мало чего понял. Вопрос подправил.

Comment: Судя по приведенному желаемому результату, 000 не подходит, соответственно, цикл должен начинаться с 001.

Comment: @usr13 если не поняли — задавайте уточняющие вопросы. Смотрите, между каждой парой соседних символов в строке может быть или не быть подчёркивание. Это два варианта, их можно закодировать одним битом. Пар на 1 меньше, чем длина строки - 3. Значит достаточно трёх бит. Получаются двоичные числа от `0b000` (или от `0b001`, если должно быть хоть одно подчёркивание) до `0b111`. В десятичной системе счисления это от 0 (1) до 7.

Answer (score 2):

Перебираем все маски, 1 - ставим подчёркивание, 0 - не ставим:

```js
function solve(s) {
  var res = [];
  
  for (var mask=0, maxmask=1<<(s.length-1); mask<maxmask; ++mask) {
    res.push(s.replace(/./g, (m,i) => mask&(1<<i) ? m+"_" : m));
  }
  
  return res;
}

var inp = document.querySelector("input"), out = document.querySelector("pre");

inp.addEventListener('input', () => { out.textContent = solve(inp.value).join("\n") })
out.textContent = solve(inp.value).join("\n");
```

```css
pre { position: absolute; top: 2em; bottom: 0; left: 8px; right: 8px; overflow: auto; }
```

```html
<input value="abcd" maxlength="10">
<pre></pre>
```